# Compile train_hog.cpp sample

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to create custom HOG detector for animal.So I want to compile `train_hog.cpp` sample from OpenCV 3.1.But I have a problem about directory.
This is a code for `load_images`

```
void load_images( const string & prefix, const string & filename, vector< Mat > & img_lst );


void load_images( const string & prefix, const string & filename, vector< Mat > & img_lst )
{
    string line;
    ifstream file;

    file.open( (prefix+filename).c_str() );
    if( !file.is_open() )
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open the list of images from " << filename << " filename." << endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    bool end_of_parsing = false;
    while( !end_of_parsing )
    {
        getline( file, line );
        if( line.empty() ) // no more file to read
        {
            end_of_parsing = true;
            break;
        }
        Mat img = imread( (prefix+line).c_str() ); // load the image
        if( img.empty() ) // invalid image, just skip it.
            continue;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        imshow( "image", img );
        waitKey( 10 );
#endif
        img_lst.push_back( img.clone() );
    }
}



int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cv::CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, "{help h|| show help message}"
            "{pd||pos_dir}{p||pos.lst}{nd||neg_dir}{n||neg.lst}");
    if (parser.has("help"))
    {
        parser.printMessage();
        exit(0);
    }
    vector< Mat > pos_lst;
vector< Mat > full_neg_lst;
vector< Mat > neg_lst;
vector< Mat > gradient_lst;
vector< int > labels;
string pos_dir = parser.get<string>("C:/Train_HOG/Franksye_dataset/Train/pos/");
string pos = parser.get<string>("Train/pos");
string neg_dir = parser.get<string>("C:/Train_HOG/Franksye_dataset/Train/neg/");
string neg = parser.get<string>("Train/neg");
if( pos_dir.empty() || pos.empty() || neg_dir.empty() || neg.empty() )

    {
        cout << "Wrong number of parameters." << endl
            << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " --pd=pos_dir -p=pos.lst --nd=neg_dir -n=neg.lst" << endl
            << "example: " << argv[0] << " --pd=/INRIA_dataset/ -p=Train/pos.lst --nd=/INRIA_dataset/ -n=Train/neg.lst" << endl;
        exit( -1 );
}
load_images( pos_dir, pos, pos_lst );
labels.assign( pos_lst.size(), +1 );
const unsigned int old = (unsigned int)labels.size();
load_images( neg_dir, neg, full_neg_lst );
sample_neg( full_neg_lst, neg_lst, Size( 96,160 ) );
labels.insert( labels.end(), neg_lst.size(), -1 );
CV_Assert( old < labels.size() );

compute_hog( pos_lst, gradient_lst, Size( 96, 160 ) );
compute_hog( neg_lst, gradient_lst, Size( 96, 160 ) );

train_svm( gradient_lst, labels );

test_it( Size( 96, 160 ) ); // change with your parameters

return 0;
}
```

`const string & prefix`, What is this parameter ? Can you tell me about it ?

And this is an error using with mingw

```
$ train_hog.exe
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (undeclared key 'C:/Train_HOG/Franksye_dataset/Train/pos/' requested) in getByName, file C:\opencv\sources\module
s\core\src\command_line_parser.cpp, line 136
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\command_line_parser.cpp:136: error: (-5) undeclared key 'C:/Train_HOG/Franksye_dataset/Train/p
os/' requested in function getByName
```

Comment: ***const string & prefix, What is this parameter ?*** It could be used for a path or you could leave it empty if your files are all in the default folder.

Comment: what's that mean @drescherjm ? example dir = C:\Train\pos\787.png

Comment: Then make prefix `C:/Train/pos/`

Comment: And for `const string & filename` ? I have 71 images in pos folder @drescherjm

Comment: That would be the filename of an existing text file that has 1 filename per line of a text file. These filenames in the text file are your image files.

Comment: thanks for the answer @drescherjm, but it's still error..

Comment: Please post the error in your question. If it is a c++ error post the function that calls this.

Comment: @drescherjm please check..

Comment: The error is in your command line parsing. From a quick look at the documentation. It looks like instead of parameters you are passing their values. I am talking about this line: `string pos_dir = parser.get<string>("C:/Train_HOG/Franksye_dataset/Train/pos/");`

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d2e/classcv_1_1CommandLineParser.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: That's Right @drescherjm.I have been open this link, but I still don't understand for using it..

Comment: `string pos_dir = parser.get<string>("C:/Train_HOG/Franksye_dataset/Train/pos/");` should be `string pos_dir = parser.get<string>("pd");`

Comment: `string pos = parser.get<string>("Train/pos");` should be `string pos = parser.get<string>("p");`

Comment: The others will be similar. After you figure that out make sure you know how to pass command line parameters to your program in your IDE.

Comment: Yeah @drescherjm..that is the default in a .cpp.But I still confused for you last answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99569/discussion-between-franksye-sipangkar-and-drescherjm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the Problem.This is a code for using `cv::CommandLineParser`..

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cv::CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, "{help h|| show help message}"
            "{@pd|C:/Train_HOG/Franksye_dataset/|pos_dir}{@p|Train/pos.lst|pos.lst}{@nd|C:/Train_HOG/Franksye_dataset/|neg_dir}{@n|Train/neg.lst|neg.lst}");
    if (parser.has("help"))
    {
        parser.printMessage();
        exit(0);
    }
    vector< Mat > pos_lst;
    vector< Mat > full_neg_lst;
    vector< Mat > neg_lst;
    vector< Mat > gradient_lst;
    vector< int > labels;
    string pos_dir = parser.get<string>("@pd");
    string pos = parser.get<string>("@p");
    string neg_dir = parser.get<string>("@nd");
    string neg = parser.get<string>("@n");
    if( pos_dir.empty() || pos.empty() || neg_dir.empty() || neg.empty() )
    {
        cout << "Wrong number of parameters." << endl
            << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " --pd=pos_dir -p=pos.lst --nd=neg_dir -n=neg.lst" << endl
            << "example: " << argv[0] << " --pd=/INRIA_dataset/ -p=Train/pos.lst --nd=/INRIA_dataset/ -n=Train/neg.lst" << endl;
        exit( -1 );
```