# Train_hog.cpp OpenCV 3.1 Example - Cannot pass the proper path parameters

Tags: c++, opencv

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572981/compile-train-hog-cpp-sample/35742081#35742081) post describes a very similar problem to mine however I am new here and was told to post a new question. Would very much appreciated anyone's help.

@Franksye I am stuck with the same problem. I am passing the path in this line 
`{@pd|C:/Cars/|pos_dir}{@p|Pos.lst|pos.lst}{@nd|C:/Cars/|neg_dir}    {@n|Neg.lst|neg.lst}");`

In the text file Pos.lst I wrote for example image0000.png, image0001.png underneath each other.

However when I run the debugger after build it gives me the below error
`The program '[0x3CF0] opencv.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).`

When creating Brake points i realized that it is exiting on the load_images function when executing `file.open((prefix + filename).c_str());`

```
void load_images(const string & prefix, const string & filename, vector< Mat   > & img_lst)
{
string line;
ifstream file;

file.open((prefix + filename).c_str());
if (!file.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Unable to open the list of images from " << filename << " filename." << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

bool end_of_parsing = false;
while (!end_of_parsing)
{
    getline(file, line);
    if (line.empty()) // no more file to read
    {
        end_of_parsing = true;
        break;
    }
    Mat img = imread((prefix + line).c_str()); // load the image
    if (img.empty()) // invalid image, just skip it.
        continue;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    imshow("image", img);
    waitKey(10);
#endif
    img_lst.push_back(img.clone());
}
}
```

I believe that I am doing something wrong when passing the path of the directory since the load_images function is not able to open the file of the images.

Can someone point me in the right direction or tell me what it is that I am doing wrong please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Such a stupid mistake thanks to Windows.

pos.lst and neg.lst where actually pos.lst.txt and neg.lst.txt because of file extension being hidden. Thanks to [This post](http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/ifstream-cant-file-249485.html) managed to solve my problem.

Had to switch to Windows because i needed to use Visual Studio will revert back to Ubuntu once this project is over!